# OpenMeeting recording feature glitch

Tags: tomcat, centos, recording, openmeetings, icedtea

Let me come to my concern directly.

I have installed OpenMeeting with following version.

Version    3.0.3-RELEASE
Revision    1621852

It's working fine but when I am using "recording" feature of OpenMeeting, I am having a glitch.

Steps I used to replicate:

1, Open up OpenMetting and go to "whiteboard" room.
2, Download the .jnlp file to record the session. I use "icedtea" for recording feature.
3, I started a session and once clicked "stop recording", it takes considerable time to stop the session, Like 2 minutes for 30 seconds actual session.
4, The problem is, when I play the above 30 seconds video + audio session, 2 minutes dead paused session is showing after the actual video.

How can I avoid this. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out this myself. It was an issue with the screen sharing/recording client IcedTea. Unfortunately there are no alternative screen recording client for openmeeting which can execute .jnlp files. OpenMeeting guys are aware of this and they are working on 3.0.4 ( will be fixing completely with 3.0.5 I guess )